# How to get Print dialog box when press button in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, button, printing, ios7

I am new to iOS. In my application, restaurant billing page is there. Now i want to print that billing page using Print button. I already create the button, now when pressing on button, it has to show the Print dialog box. So would you please send me the code for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use uiprintinteractioncontroller to Print data
Check this:
http://vivianaranha.com/airprinting-tutorial-in-3-steps/